# How to find the degree of connection in a social network using recursion

Tags: sql, oracle

Imagine, you are looking at a social network graph of millions of users.  Imagine Facebook users who are in different Facebook Groups. Let me give the following example:

We start with `Jeff`.  `Jeff` has a degree of connection with himself of `0`.

`Rohit` is in the same Facebook group as `Jeff`, so his degree of connection with `Jeff` is `1`.

`Linda` is in a facebook group with `Rohit`, but not in one with `Jeff`. Her degree connection with `Jeff` is, therefore `2`.

This same phenomenon goes on and on. Now we want to create a query in SQL that can find all users in the `user` table that have a degree of connection with `Jeff` of `3 or less`.  We have the following 2 tables:

`user`

| name | person_id |
| --- | --- |
| Jeff | 1 |
| Rohit | 2 |
| Linda | 3 |
| Sid | 4 |
| Jin | 5 |

`group_in`

| group_id | person_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |

What query could find and return all the `person_id`s and `degrees_of_connection` for all `users` with a `degrees_of_connection <= 3` with `Jeff` using just these two tables?  The output should show that `Jeff`, `Rohit`, `Linda`, and `Sid` are all within 3 degrees of connectivity.  Whereas `Jin` would not be included in the results as he is 4 degrees of connection away

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag the specific database only.

Comment: Thank you, this one is specifically for Oracle

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: The sample data is insufficient for thorough testing. For example, you don't have any people connected to `Jeff`, but with a degree of connection greater than 3 (so that you will verify that such users are **not** returned by the query).

Comment: @mathguy sorry about that, I just updated the tables to include a proper data sample size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following which uses a recursive cte to find the degree of connection between users. The final projection uses joins to retrieve the respective user names[.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mWUZ36zMPkNrZeurViBWqx/1)

```sql
WITH user_connections(person_id_1,person_id_2,group_id,no_con) AS (
    SELECT 
        p1.person_id, 
        p2.person_id , 
        p2.group_id ,
        case when p2.person_id is null then 0 else 1 end as no_con
    from group_in p1
    left join group_in p2 on p1.group_id = p2.group_id and p1.person_id < p2.person_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
         p1.person_id_1, 
         p3.person_id, 
         p3.group_id ,
         1+no_con 
    from user_connections p1
    inner join group_in p2 on (
                              p2.group_id <> p1.group_id and
                              p2.person_id = p1.person_id_2 and
                              p1.person_id_2 is not null) 
    inner join group_in p3 on p3.group_id = p2.group_id and 
                              p3.person_id <> p2.person_id
    where no_con < 3
)
SELECT 
    con_name.person_id,
    con_name.name,
    uc.no_con as degrees_of_connection
FROM 
    users u 
INNER JOIN user_connections uc ON u.person_id = uc.person_id_1
INNER JOIN users con_name on con_name.person_id = uc.person_id_2
WHERE u.name = 'Jeff';
```

| person_id | name | degrees_of_connection |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Rohit | 1 |
| 3 | Linda | 2 |
| 4 | Sid | 3 |

[Working Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c65bdaa2d719f2f5c4dc11e35f14c790)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thank you for your hard work in responding to this.  Does this code scale up to thousands or millions of rows? I'm looking into implementing this now

Comment: I will admit that joins can be expensive but with your data model, limiting the recursive cte (eg. `where no_con < 3` )with this is the ideal option here. Utilize indexes where possible and this should help your scaling factor. You may also review more performance tuning tips [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/text.101/b10729/aoptim.htm).

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate this and will let you know if I have follow up questions while implementing